# How to change "asksaveasfile" dialog overwrite message?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently using `asksaveasfile` to save the file, and it is working fine. When I try to overwrite a file a dialog box pops up with a warning. I want to know if there is a way to change the text in that warning.

I am asking because it is currently displaying the path to the file in the warning, instead of the name of the file. For example the warning is:

```
File "home/work/name1.txt" already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?
```

But I want to change it to:

```
File "name1" already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?
```

Comment: on my mac it only shows `name1` like you want it too, so you can blame this behaviour on your OS, tkinter has no control over that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to change it.